# Can we use wxWidget to save a webpage onto the disk

Tags: html, download, wxwidgets

I was using wget with system call (c++) to save a webpage from internet to my HD in a program. Now I want to use wxWidget to do the same. Is there anyway I can do that and still have the generic behaviour of wget? (i.e. i give a link to a pdf file n then a pdf file is saved)

I found this link http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Download_a_file_from_internet

but I have no idea how to convert wxString to a pdf/mp3 file according to the url entered.

Could anyone help please. I am working on an open source project for the first time and I encountered this wxWidget just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wxHTTP](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_h_t_t_p.html) (as described [here](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=122403&sid=4b5a179d47c78ebd0be224c4f0f3c8fa#p122403)) or use wxURL and [GetInputStream()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_u_r_l.html#a6974f1d2c13a6ef721e2b93c84e5e376)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did use wxURL but is there anyway to get the type of file I am saving? Like if I am saving it as a pdf/mp3 etc? As of now i am just storing it as something.html! Can I make it generic?

Comment: You probably could try to use wxHTTP. It has GetHeader() method. Content-Type header should do the thing. Or try to use wxCURL or just libcurl

Comment: hmm.. ryt now I am giving it as an option to the user to enter the file type. Should work.. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy using wget with a system call, then why not continue to do so?

wxWidgets is a GUI framework, with a lot of extra convenience functions included.  You don't HAVE to use them.  You can still use whatever C++ features, utilities and packages that your are familiar with.

Here is a link to [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The thing is I am trying to add a feature to an existing project. They use wxWidget extensively and it makes the program work on windows and linux systems. If I use the current code it wont build on windows right? So I need to rewrite the code using wxWdiget.